# Trouble grabbing text from a website using Jsoup

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to grab a price from an amazon [link.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00H2T37SO)

Here's the html I'm focusing on:

```
<div class="buying" id="priceBlock">
    <table class="product">
        <tbody>
            <tr id="actualPriceRow">
                <td class="priceBlockLabelPrice" id="actualPriceLabel">Price:</td>
                <td id="actualPriceContent">
                    <span id="actualPriceValue">
                        <b class="priceLarge">
                                $1.99
                        </b>
                    </span>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I'm trying to grab that **$1.99** text.

Here's my code that is trying to grab it.

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                // Connect to the web site
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                // Get the html document title
                Elements trs = document.select("table.product");



                for (Element tr : trs)
                {
                    Elements tds = tr.select("b.priceLarge");
                    Element price1 = tds.first();
                    String str1 = price1.text();
                    System.out.println(str1);
                    String str2 = str1.replaceAll( "[$,]", "" );
                    double aInt = Double.parseDouble(str2);
                    System.out.println("Price: " + aInt);

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Why isn't this code working?

Comment: You should be able to get at that using their selector-syntax: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax. In your case, search on the `priceLarge` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a `user agent` so the site won't reject you as a [bot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_bot). You should also add some timeout limit in order to override the default one, which might be too short for you. Three seconds is a good option but feel free to change it at will. `timeout(0)` will wait as long as the server needs to give some response. If you don't want a limit use that. There is also some weird `DOM` parsing you are doing, which is causing a `NullPointerException`. Try this

```
String url = "http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00H2T37SO/?tag=stackoverfl08-20";
Document doc = Jsoup
                .connect(url)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36")
                .timeout(3000)
                .get();

Elements prices = doc.select("table.product b.priceLarge");
for (Element pr : prices)
{
    String priceWithCurrency = pr.text();
    System.out.println(priceWithCurrency);
    String priceAsText = priceWithCurrency.replaceAll( "[$,]", "" );
    double priceAsNumber = Double.parseDouble(priceAsText);
    System.out.println("Price: " + priceAsNumber);
}
```

Comment: Interesting, it works! Thanks so much! I spent hours trying to figure out what was wrong, since it was working for a different link with a different html location. You really saved some stress!

Comment: No problem. Have fun.